# ASP.NET MVC3 URL and hiding Id's

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, url-routing

I have a heap of entities that are keyed by ID. In one screen I load a "Subject" based on the ID like so: `"/Results/Subject/53"` On that same screen I have a combo box that maintains a list of all subjects. The user can change the selection in this combo to another subject and I load the results for that subject using ajax. When I do this the URL in the browser is stale as I might be now be looking at `/Results/Subject/45` If a user reloads I reload the original document and not the new one.

I would either like to update the URL (which sounds hacky as) or I would like to base my navigation on something else besides the Id as part of the URL. How can I do this? How can I load controllers for specific items without specifying the Id as part of the URL.

Comment: It sounds like you could do with some kind of history plugin to keep track of your ajax changes. I've had some good results with [jQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way would be to ditch the ajax when that drop-down changes, and just navigate to a new url (/Results/Subject/NewID).

If you want to keep the ajax, you could just put the key at the end of the url with a # like "/Results/Subject#53", then load it via Ajax (the #53 will not be passed over to the server). That way, when the user changes the drop-down, you can navigate to "/Results/Subject#NewID" without it reloading the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass the id via the HTTP GET parameter: `/Results/Subject?id=45` or HTTP POST parameter.

However, I doubt that this will answer your question.

A colleague of mine has encountered the similar problem, and he solved it by altering the browser URL string (by attaching a specific #anchor to it).